# Resultset to display in text box by splitting

Tags: java, swing, resultset

```
         public class Time extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/** Creates new form Time */
public Time() {
    initComponents();
    generate();
}

public void generate()
{
    try
    {
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:timetable","sa","nish1990()");
    String str="select c_name from course where sem_id=1";
    Statement str1=con.createStatement();
    ResultSet res1=str1.executeQuery(str);

   // THIS THE RS PLACE 

    while(res1.next())
    {
        String s=res1.getString(1);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,s);
    }

    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        System.out.println("SQL Exception :: "+e.toString());
    }

    catch(Exception e)

    {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }  
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            new Time().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField6;
private javax.swing.JTextField tf1;
private javax.swing.JTextField tf2;
// End of variables declaration
   }
```

SEE MY DATABASE CONTAINS THESE INFO :

C_NAME
 C
  COBOL
  MATH

its able to retrieve all the data... i dont know how to split and display in text box..

**rs.getString(1) contains C Cobol n Math ...
so how do u take just C n display it
each of the item n display**

Comment: what do you mean by "split" ? If you want to get each column separately, just use getString(xx) or getInt(xx) where xx is a column number (1-based).

Comment: why don't you store each row in an container like an arraylist then display it? you should really close your resultset and connection.

Comment: how to store to arraylist and display it... can u tell me

Comment: i don't know what you want to do really... would you want to split the string that is returned by the resultset with that query? or as Snicolas suggested get each column? if the latter then you should modify your query.

Comment: i need to display them in textbox... but the values i am only to fetch the last one...so i need them to pass to array... and display them... how to send the values to array...and display them

Comment: rs.getString(1) contains C Cobol n Math ... so how do u take just C n display it each of the item n display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rs.getString(1) contains C Cobol n Math ... so how do u take just C n display it each of the item n display –
if that's what you're asking then do something like this

```
    String s;   

    while(res1.next()){
       s=res1.getString(1);
    }

  String [] splitted = s.split(" ");
   for(String aSplit: splitted){
        System.out.println(aSplit);
   }
```

I'm guessing you are not a fan of normalization. if you are then you don't even have to split your data.

Comment: @pif---appreciate ur help...i am able to split them into three seperate values but how do i display each one of them in a textbox..tht cannot be done within a for() loop

Comment: Create an Array containing your trext fields. Then you can access each text field within the for() loop.

Comment: how can you display anything without a for loop? do wat @camickr suggested.